# CloudKit - How did my Entities end up in a Private Database (and can I change to Public)?

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

In xCode I created some Core Data Entities for my app in the Default Configuration and I set up my Data Controller class as follows:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
       let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer 
        class DataController: ObservableObject {
            let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
            init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
                container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "KoyaQuest", managedObjectModel: Self.model)
                if inMemory { 
                    container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
                }
                container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        fatalError("Fatal error loading data store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
    ...
    }
```

Over in CloudKit Dashboard, I notice that any records being created are stored in the "Private Database." And I'm not sure how that happened as I don't recall (nor can I find any evidence of) my specifying the type of database. I am in Development. Is this a default of that mode?
Also, since I really want these data to be public, is there a way to make the change? I've scoured Apple's documentation and other sources but can't seem to find a simple answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Soon after posting this question, I re-discovered [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10650/) (which I had actually watched before!). In case anyone has the same confusion as I did, I'm sharing here. Note that one of the two indices that need to be added to the CloudKit schema seems to have been re-named to "modifiedTimestamp" (at least that's the only one I see that looks close enough to "modifiedAt" as shown in the video).